Does a crash cause a watchdog timeout or is the timeout a result of the crash?
I'm getting a crash on my system. systemd-udev.service is crashing as seen in the logs below:
Apr 03 20:15:04 dut-3 charon-systemd[23290]: sending keep alive to 194.1.1.1[40055]
Apr 03 20:15:04 dut-3 charon-systemd[23290]: sending keep alive to 194.1.1.1[40055]
Apr 03 20:15:04 dut-3 charon-systemd[23290]: sending keep alive to 194.1.1.1[40055]
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcoredump.slice - Slice /system/systemd-coredump.
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: Started systemd-coredump@0-276426-0.service - Process Core Dump (PID 276426/UID 0).
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Killing.
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Killing process 1546 (systemd-udevd) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: Started systemd-coredump@1-276430-0.service - Process Core Dump (PID 276430/UID 0).
...
Apr 03 20:19:07 dut-3 systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
...
Apr 03 20:17:00 dut-3 systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!

In trying to debug the crash, I'm wondering if the crash is due to the watchdog timeout or if the watchdog timeout occurs because of the crash. Specifically, systemd-udevd.service has crash and isn't able to send a message to the watchdog.
